# Too many open ports in Debian 8

Tags: debian, security, services

The IT department has given me 3 virtual servers with Debian 8 for my area, which I will manage (but they have some monitoring tools).

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-11 13:33 ART
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.53
Host is up (0.0043s latency).
Not shown: 983 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
1/tcp     open  tcpmux
22/tcp    open  ssh
79/tcp    open  finger
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
119/tcp   open  nntp
143/tcp   open  imap
1080/tcp  open  socks
1524/tcp  open  ingreslock
2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp
6667/tcp  open  irc
12345/tcp open  netbus
31337/tcp open  Elite
32771/tcp open  sometimes-rpc5
32772/tcp open  sometimes-rpc7
32773/tcp open  sometimes-rpc9
32774/tcp open  sometimes-rpc11

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.28 seconds
jsivil@jsivil:~$ nmap 192.168.x.52

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-11 13:36 ART
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.52
Host is up (0.0046s latency).
Not shown: 982 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
1/tcp     open  tcpmux
22/tcp    open  ssh
79/tcp    open  finger
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
119/tcp   open  nntp
143/tcp   open  imap
1080/tcp  open  socks
1524/tcp  open  ingreslock
2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp
6667/tcp  open  irc
12345/tcp open  netbus
31337/tcp open  Elite
32771/tcp open  sometimes-rpc5
32772/tcp open  sometimes-rpc7
32773/tcp open  sometimes-rpc9
32774/tcp open  sometimes-rpc11
50000/tcp open  ibm-db2

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.53 seconds
jsivil@jsivil:~$ nmap 192.168.x.54

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-05-11 13:36 ART
Nmap scan report for 192.168.x.54
Host is up (0.0071s latency).
Not shown: 983 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
1/tcp     open  tcpmux
22/tcp    open  ssh
79/tcp    open  finger
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
119/tcp   open  nntp
143/tcp   open  imap
1080/tcp  open  socks
1524/tcp  open  ingreslock
2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp
6667/tcp  open  irc
12345/tcp open  netbus
31337/tcp open  Elite
32771/tcp open  sometimes-rpc5
32772/tcp open  sometimes-rpc7
32773/tcp open  sometimes-rpc9
32774/tcp open  sometimes-rpc11

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.27 seconds
```

Its way too many open ports for me. In my Home, I have Ubuntu 14.04 servers and only port 22 and 80 are open.

What should I do? Are these ports risky?

Comment: Ports 22 is an SSH port and Port 80 is for HTTP requests (web surfing). These ports can only be risky if they are not properly secured

Comment: [Also posted on Security](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/88996/too-many-open-ports-in-debian-8). [Don't do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `netstat -pan --tcp --udp` (Linux-specific syntax) on each server to find out which programs are listening to which ports, and disable those you don't need.  Don't leave them running just is case, *any* open port is a potential risk.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that these ports are managed by `portsentry`, and seems to be a software to block port scanners.

Answer (score 0):

They are not risky(except for finger) but it depend if can reach from outside(internet) or from local net,in the first case they are risky,but
depend if you must use service associated or not.
My rule are
A service is necessary / used? Y=OK N=Simply shutdown it and turn off on boot
Is possible to upgrade to secure service(imaps instead of imap)? Y=do it N=not possible,retain old service
Must important is also firewalling,some services(cifs,nfs) must be accessible only on LAN,imho,but i know some mad people which use nfs outside.